# Dealing with Jackson Deserialization with JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

When I use an ObjectMapper configured as:

```
        DefaultTyping applicability = ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT;
        TypeResolverBuilder<?> typer = DefaultTypeResolverBuilder.construct(applicability, validator);
        String propertyName = "type";
        typer = typer.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, null);
        typer = typer.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        typer = typer.typeProperty(propertyName);

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDefaultTyping(typer);
```

It produces JSON like:

```
 {
   "type": "ShortClassName",
   ...
 }
```

The type does not have the full package name as expected. However trying to deserialize using this object mapper cause:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException`

How do I specify the base package name as part of the object mapper configuration so that the serialized JSON only has the classname?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapper for a specific Object by using `mapper.readerFor(...)` and specifying which type to extract, in this case this would be

```java
ObjectReader shortClassNameReader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<ShortClassName>(){})
```

Where `ShortClassName` is your class's name.

Then you can use this `ObjectReader` with `readValue` to deserialize the JSON.

Comment: In the context of Spring MVC, is there a way to set this globally so the controller methods can make the objects from JSON with the type reference set?

Comment: Well I believe, if your parameters for the controller methods are the right type (in this case `ShortClassName`) Spring MVC should do this automatically. But then you should probably use jackson's annotations, in particular `@JsonTypeInfo` (see https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/jackson-json-type-info-annotation.html). Then - I think - would Spring use this annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ayk - your solution works if the class name is itself the one to be deserialized but if it is nested inside the JSON for another class, it does not work. However I got it working by defining a custom `typeIdResolver` that translates the ID from/to object in `idFromValue` and `typeFromId` respectively. This then works globally without the need for annotation on each object involved in the serialization.